# Android Studio Code Dont Work On Android Version 9.0

Tags: android-studio, version, okhttp

Please My Android App works well in any android app version but dont work on android 9.0 ??
there is no errors display when run the code from android studio on emulator ..

this is my login_activity.java

```
package com.steam.carwash.activities;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.icanstudioz.sclient.R;
import com.steam.carwash.Server.Server;
import com.steam.carwash.custom.MyApplication;
import com.steam.carwash.fragment.ForgotPassword;
import com.steam.carwash.model.ResObj;
import com.steam.carwash.model.User;
import com.lzy.okgo.OkGo;
import com.lzy.okgo.callback.Callback;
import com.lzy.okgo.model.HttpParams;
import com.lzy.okgo.model.Progress;
import com.lzy.okgo.model.Response;
import com.lzy.okgo.request.base.Request;
import com.norbsoft.typefacehelper.TypefaceHelper;
import com.steam.carwash.permissionhelper.ActivityManagePermission;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import okhttp3.ResponseBody;



public class LoginActivity extends ActivityManagePermission {
EditText email, password;
Button login;
TextView register, forgot;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);
    bindViews();

}

private void bindViews() {

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgress.setTitle("Processing...");
    mProgress.setMessage("Please wait...");
    mProgress.setCancelable(false);
    mProgress.setIndeterminate(true);

    email =  findViewById(R.id.input_email);
    password = findViewById(R.id.input_password);
    login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    register = findViewById(R.id.txt_register);
    forgot = findViewById(R.id.txt_forgot);
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (validate()) {
                final String eml = email.getText().toString().trim();
                final String pwd = password.getText().toString().trim();


                FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loginUser(eml, pwd,instanceIdResult.getToken());
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        loginUser(eml, pwd,"");
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });

    forgot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ForgotPassword.class));
        }
    });

    TypefaceHelper.typeface(email, MyApplication.getLight());
    TypefaceHelper.typeface(password, MyApplication.getLight());
    TypefaceHelper.typeface(register, MyApplication.getRegular());
    TypefaceHelper.typeface(forgot, MyApplication.getRegular());
    TypefaceHelper.typeface(login, MyApplication.getRegular());


}

private Boolean validate() {

    String eml = email.getText().toString().trim();
    String pwd = password.getText().toString().trim();
    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(eml).matches()) {
        email.setError(getString(R.string.email_is_invalid));
    } else if (pwd.isEmpty()) {
        password.setError(getString(R.string.password_is_required));
    } else {
        //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Is Valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void loginUser(String email, String password, String token) {
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "okiii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    HttpParams params = new HttpParams();
    params.put("type", "simple");
    params.put("utype", "0");
    params.put("email", email);
    params.put("password", password);
    params.put("fcm_token", token);
    OkGo.<ResObj<User>>post(Server.BASE_URL + "user/login").params(params).execute(new Callback<ResObj<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onStart(Request<ResObj<User>, ? extends Request> request) {
            //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Response<ResObj<User>> response) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login On Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (response.body() != null) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Good Job", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ResObj<User> userResObj = response.body();
                User user = userResObj.getData();
                HttpParams params1=new HttpParams();
                params1.put("access_token",user.getAccess_token());
                params1.put("user_id",user.getId());

                OkGo.getInstance().addCommonParams(params1);
                MyApplication.getInstance().setUser(user);
                MyApplication.getInstance().createLoginSession(user.getName(), user.getEmail(), user.getId(), user.getFcm_token(),user.getAccess_token());
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Good b", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                finish();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCacheSuccess(Response<ResObj<User>> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Response<ResObj<User>> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        }

        @Override
        public void uploadProgress(Progress progress) {

        }

        @Override
        public void downloadProgress(Progress progress) {

        }

        @Override
        public ResObj<User> convertResponse(okhttp3.Response response) throws Throwable {
            try {
                ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();

                String s = responseBody.string();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (jsonObject.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                    return new Gson().fromJson(s, new TypeToken<ResObj<User>>() {
                    }.getType());
                } else {
                    MyApplication.getInstance().showToast(LoginActivity.this, jsonObject.getString("data"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Log.e("catch", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
            return null;
        }
    });

}
}
```

and this is my androidmainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.icanstudioz.sclient">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />


<application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:name="com.steam.carwash.custom.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/splash"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/boy"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode">
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
    <activity android:name="com.steam.carwash.activities.SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.steam.carwash.fragment.ForgotPassword"/>

    <activity android:name="com.steam.carwash.permissionhelper.ActivityManagePermission"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.steam.carwash.activities.HomeActivity"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden" />
    <activity android:name="com.steam.carwash.activities.LoginActivity" />

    <activity android:name="com.steam.carwash.activities.PaymentActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.steam.carwash.activities.RegisterActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity android:name="com.steam.carwash.activities.fullImage" />

    <service android:name="com.steam.carwash.Server.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/c_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
    <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
         notification message.  -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBX8-V0iihmTnrgwYlyI5GdP0GKjwfTTd8" />
</application>
```

when run this on android version 8.0 or below its work well ... but the problem is on version 9 or above ??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dont work"? Is it crashing? Does it just not function as you expect? If so, how? Please [edit] your question to better explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just put the below line in manifest under application tag and try

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

if doesnt work try adding below line 
`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true`
 under application tag and even if it doesnt work try adding 
`android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config`
 in application tag where network_security_config.xml is
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>`
Create xml under res directory and then network_security_config.xml in xml folder